Extract continuous cell values from multiple excel files using Python
The aim of my task is firstly to extract values from continuous cells of a single excel file. Then the same extraction method will be performed on the remaining excel files of the same folder until the loop ends
For example,
I want to extract values from row 'A283:A9000' at excel file 1. After the extraction at excel file 1 is finished, the value from row 'A283:A9000' at excel file 2 will be extracted, then the extraction at the same rows 'A283:A9000' will be continued on excel file 3, excel file 4, excel files 5 and so on.
I learn how to extract values from multiple excel files from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7YkQpcB4fg
The code works well when the values from non-continuous cells are extracted. However, when I try to use the code to extract value from continuous cells ('A283:A9000') of the same sheet, the code fails.
I know the problem occurs when I try to use the code to extract values from continuous cells of the same sheet, but I am not sure how to fix the code to custom with my case. I think the problem is located at the line (cells = ['C11', 'C15', 'D15', 'C16', 'A283:A9000']).
Could anyone give me help?
Cheers
Here is the code that I have tried.
import os
import openpyxl 

folder = r'C:\PhD study\GIS\Wind_Downscale\test_one'
output_file = 'C:\PhD study\GIS\Wind_Downscale\Wind_data_forecast_time.xlsx'

output_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
output_sheet = output_wb.active
output_sheet.title = 'Wind Data for Forecast Time'

cells = ['C11', 'C15', 'D15', 'C16', 'A283:A9000']

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
        
        file = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
       
   
        values = [workbook.active[cell].value for cell in cells]

        
        output_sheet.append(values)
        
output_wb.save(output_file)

Here is the error messsage:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File C:\\Conda5\\lib\\site-packages\\spyder_kernels\\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
exec(code, globals, locals)

File c:\\users\\kxz237.spyder-py3\\temp.py:29
values = \[workbook.active\[cell\].value for cell in cells\]

File c:\\users\\kxz237.spyder-py3\\temp.py:29 in \<listcomp\>
values = \[workbook.active\[cell\].value for cell in cells\]

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'


The ability to use cell addressing is provided for convenience in interactive sessions. For single cells Openpyxl returns a single cell, for every other range it returns a generator of tuples. For programmatic access you should always use ws.iter_rows(), here with values_only=True and probably read-only mode.

Yes you are trying to use 'A283:A9000' as a single cells' co-ordinate hence the attribute error.
An alternative is you can treat every element of your 'cells' list as a range 
cells = ['C11', 'C15', 'D15', 'C16', 'A283:A9000'] 
so for each element the code extracts all the cells that the range covers;
for 'C11' that would be just 'C11'
for 'A283:A9000' that would be 'A283', 'A284', 'A285', 'A286', ...
Use the Openpyxl util openpyxl.utils.cell.cols_from_range(<cells element>) on each element in the cells list.
import os
import openpyxl 

folder = r'C:\PhD study\GIS\Wind_Downscale\test_one'
output_file = 'C:\PhD study\GIS\Wind_Downscale\Wind_data_forecast_time.xlsx'

output_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
output_sheet = output_wb.active
output_sheet.title = 'Wind Data for Forecast Time'

cells = ['C11', 'C15', 'D15', 'C16', 'A283:A9000']

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
        file = os.path.join(folder, filename)

        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)

        #values = [workbook.active[cell].value for cell in cells]

        for rng in cells:  # Each element in 'cells' list 
            ### Get all cells in the elements range
            for allcells in openpyxl.utils.cell.cols_from_range(rng):
                ### allcells is a tuple of all individual cells in the range rng
                for cell in allcells:  # Extract each cell
                    values = workbook.active[cell].value

                    output_sheet.append([values])

output_wb.save(output_file)

Additional details FYI
There are two Openpyxl utilities that will return the individual cells of a range
openpyxl.utils.cell.cols_from_range(range_string)  and 
openpyxl.utils.cell.rows_from_range(range_string) 
Either could be used in this scenario given the range provided is just one column.
However if your range covered two or more columns then the way each would return the individual cells is; 
cols_from_range, cell from each row down the first column, then same down next column etc
rows_from_range, cells across all columns in first row, then all cells in all columns in the second row etc.
i.e. a range 'C3:D4' would return
cols_from_range,  'C3', 'C4', 'D3', 'D4'
rows_from_range, 'C3', 'D3', 'C4', 'D4' 

Yesterday I saw someone used this approach and I considered to adopt the solution, but I did not know how to custom it for my case. Thanks for the very detailed explanation, it really help me understand the approach and save my time.

I don't know if openpyxl has a method for reading from cell ranges (what you are referring to as continuous cells) which may be faster. However, notice that your range of cells could also be represented by list of individual cell addresses. So if you first use a list comprehension to build a list of these individual cell addresses, it should work.
Try replacing this line in your code:
cells = [f"A{i}" for i in range(283, 9000+1)]

This will generate a list like ['A283', 'A284' ... 'A9000']
So, the whole thing in your example (assuming you don't actually want those initial cells 'C11', 'C15', 'D15', 'C16' in your list) would be...
import os
import openpyxl 

folder = r'C:\PhD study\GIS\Wind_Downscale\test_one'
output_file = 'C:\PhD study\GIS\Wind_Downscale\Wind_data_forecast_time.xlsx'

output_wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
output_sheet = output_wb.active
output_sheet.title = 'Wind Data for Forecast Time'

cells = [f"A{i}" for i in range(283, 9000+1)]

for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'):
        
        file = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
       
   
        values = [workbook.active[cell].value for cell in cells]

        
        output_sheet.append(values)
        
output_wb.save(output_file)


You can just combine the list comprehension with the additional cells cells = ['C11', 'C15', 'D15', 'C16'] + [f"A{i}" for i in range(283, 9000 + 1)]

If you don't know what the library can do, you shouldn't really make suggestions about it.

Thanks Matt and Moken, actually both methods on the page work very well. However, stackoverflow only allows me to accept one answer so I have to choose only one of them.

@CharlieClark I don't think that's a very constructive observation in this case. Demonstrably I know enough to solve OP's problem exactly as described, and only mentioned my unfamiliarity with potential range methods in openpyxl to acknowledge that they're not necessary here but might be worth a look if performance is unsatisfactory when handling many rows/sheets.

The criticism is valid as you're obviously not aware of the API that should be used here: values = (row[0] for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=283, max_row=9000, max_col=1, values_only=True))
